# On Drools 4 0 7, observing rules are skipped randomly after rule base creation

Tags: drools

Rule base is getting corrupt, objectTypeNodes is getting changed.
Issue comes randomly and difficult to reproduce. It comes after lot of rule base compilation.

We are running multiple threads.

Comment: Why do you use such an old version? If you have been using it for so many years and the "issue" started after some change you should be able to guess what causes it. Your description makes it likely that a race condition is responsible.

Comment: I got the exact issue now. The ObjectHashMap returns null even it has object in it. Problem I think is of resize() method being non-synchronous.